# What does Boost's build warning about "non-free usage requirements" mean?

Tags: boost, build, warnings, boost-build

When I build Boost (1.69) with `b2` on my system (Devuan ASCII), I get several warning messages about "non-free usage":

```
warning: non-free usage requirements <runtime-link>shared ignored
warning: in main-target build_options at libs/locale/build/Jamfile.v2:414
warning: non-free usage requirements <runtime-link>shared ignored
warning: in main-target build_flags at libs/locale/build/Jamfile.v2:415
```

My questions:

- What do these messages mean?
- Why am I getting them?
- Can I / Should I do something to avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

> What do these messages mean?

It means that there's a build feature that normally propagates "downwards" is being specified to propagate "upwards". In this case as a "usage-requirement". This can be a problem as it can cause your target to change how it's built from using a different library.

> Why am I getting them?

They come from usage-requirements in the Boost.Locale library [here](https://github.com/boostorg/locale/blob/boost-1.69.0/build/Jamfile.v2#L414). AFAICT it's a bug in the library's build file.

> Can I / Should I do something to avoid them?

I think you (a) should report it as a bug to the authors and (b) ignore it for now since as far as I can tell those targets do not affect the overall build of the library itself nor of other Boost libraries.